# What is happening?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was bored while watching youtube and I started to program just basic randomisation of characters. And then I thought of three letter words that have 36 different characters to choose from.

```
import random
file = open("C:\\Users\\nikol\\Downloads\\ThreeLetters.txt","w+",encoding = 
"utf-8")
word = []
char = 0
wordloop = 0
words = []
currentword = ""
while wordloop < 46656:
    for n in range(3):
        char = random.randint(1,36)
        if char == 1:
            word.append("a")
        if char == 2:
            word.append("b")
        if char == 3:
            word.append("c")
        if char == 4:
            word.append("d")
        if char == 5:
            word.append("e")
        if char == 6:
            word.append("f")
        if char == 7:
            word.append("g")
        if char == 8:
            word.append("h")
        if char == 9:
            word.append("i")
        if char == 10:
            word.append("j")
        if char == 11:
            word.append("k")
        if char == 12:
            word.append("l")
        if char == 13:
            word.append("m")
        if char == 14:
            word.append("n")
        if char == 15:
            word.append("o")
        if char == 16:
            word.append("p")
        if char == 17:
            word.append("q")
        if char == 18:
            word.append("r")
        if char == 19:
            word.append("s")
        if char == 20:
            word.append("t")
        if char == 21:
            word.append("u")
        if char == 22:
            word.append("v")
        if char == 23:
            word.append("w")
        if char == 24:
            word.append("x")
        if char == 25:
            word.append("y")
        if char == 26:
            word.append("z")
        if char == 27:
            word.append("0")
        if char == 28:
            word.append("1")
        if char == 29:
            word.append("2")
        if char == 30:
            word.append("3")
        if char == 31:
            word.append("4")
        if char == 32:
            word.append("5")
        if char == 33:
            word.append("6")
        if char == 34:
            word.append("7")
        if char == 35:
            word.append("8")
        if char == 36:
            word.append("9")

    for n in range(len(word)):
        currentword = currentword + word[n]
    word = []
    words.append(currentword)
    currentword = ""
    wordloop += 1

words = sorted(words)
for n in range(len(words)):
    file.write(str(words[n]) + ",")
file.close()
```

This code lets me make 46656 or 36^3 three letter words, because that is how many characters I am using. The weird thing about this is that when it writes to a file I get things like: 〰ⰰ〰ⰱ〰ⰱ〰ⰲ〰ⰳ〰ⰳ〰ⰶ〰ⰶ〰ⰷ〰ⰸ〰ⱡ〰Ɫ〰Ᵽ〰Ᵽ〰Ɽ〰ⱦ〰ⱨ. Why? What is this? Is it Unicode?
Python 3.5 BTW

Comment: Side note: "What is happening?" the title could use a better description. See [ask]

Comment: How are you opening the file? What editor? What encoding?

Comment: Side note: you are indeed writing 36³ "words" but these are not all *possible* combinations of `a..z0..9`, because you are picking them at random. If you want all combinations, you need to replace `random` with something from `itertools`.

Comment: why the big `if` and using a random integer to get a character? use `word = random.choices("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", k=3)` to get a list of 3 characters from the given string ...

Comment: TrebuchetMS - Yes it could, however, I am learning this in school and as school has finished, I can't ask my teachers for help. That is why I came to this site which has helped me a lot in the past with coding.
usr2564301 - I don't want all combinations, i want to see how many combinations of "red" or "the" will show up in a random generator.
Patrick Artner -  The big "if" is because that is the only thing I knew and I could code much easier. I could've used loops and lists to make it shorter, I didn't use "random.choices" because I didn't know it existed till now. Thanks for the new info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it Unicode?

Yes. But you may be surprised to learn that your `"a"`, `"b"`, etc. are *also* Unicode.

You get these weird characters because you open or view your output file as a two-byte Unicode encoded text.

Some of those codes you see fall above the range `U+2C00`, where that first code is the comma and the second one is one of your letters. For example, ⰶ is this: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2c36/index.htm. Other weird characters are also formed by combining two random characters in one double-wide Unicode value.

Inspecting the resulting file with a hex editor shows you indeed got the expected 3-letter combinations, separated by a comma:

```
0hp,1gb,1u4,23x,2xj,30m,3pe,4kd,59u,75y,7l5,7od
.. etc.
```

For some reason your text file viewer thinks this should be 2-byte Unicode text. If you fix that, you'll see your code worked as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You interprete a unicode file wrongly. You also can simplify your code a bit:

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase,digits
words = [] 
chars = ascii_lowercase+digits
for _ in range(10): # 46656 - reduced amount to 10 
    # words.append( random.choices(chars,k=3) ) # python 3.6 has choices
    words.append( [ random.choice(chars),random.choice(chars),
                    random.choice(chars)] )    # python 3.5 got no choices

words.sort()
with open("./ThreeLetters.txt","w+",encoding ="utf-8") as file:
    for w in words:
        file.write(str(w) + ",")
```

You can print the file without mishap in your console like so:

```
# and output it again            
with open("./ThreeLetters.txt", encoding ="utf-8") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', 'n'],['9', '6', 'f'],['j', 'o', 'k'],['n', '1', '4'],['n', 'o', '9'],['s', 'c', 'l'],['v', 'l', 'b'],['v', 'o', 'a'],['w', '7', 'u'],['z', '3', '6'],
```

I fixed the file writing to be more locally - not far to the top and also used `with open(..) as f:` to make it more robust.

See:

- [with open(..) as ..:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)